# How to add Spotlight comments to the bundled OS X apps?

Tags: macos, applications, spotlight

I'd like to add a Spotlight comment to TextEdit.app. Is that possible?

What I've done:

- Open Finder
- Browse to /Applications/
- Select TextEdit
- Press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> (Get Info)
- Click the lock icon to unlock the dialog
- Click on Spotlight comment text field
- Nothing happens. Even cut, copy and paste options are disabled in the context menu.

This seems to be the case for all the other OS X bundled apps as well (Font Book, iChat, iCal, …)

I *could* create an alias of the app and give comments to it, but are there any other ways?

Comment: You could also [run Finder as root or use xattr](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64412/how-can-i-have-spotlight-comments-actually-get-indexed-by-spotlight/64416#64416).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have write permission for the bundle. After you open the lock:

- Select 'Read & Write' permission for 'everyone'
- Add your comments
- Restore the permissions

Comment: You could also try to set them as root rather than changing permissions. Something like `sudo xattr -w com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment "shazam" /Applications/Text\ Edit.app` should do the trick

Comment: @bmike, say, first time I'd like to flag a comment as *"Not a comment — This was posted as a comment but it does answer the question. It should possibly be an answer."* if I could :-D

Comment: I didn't have time to test it well - xattr isn't the best documented or stable command on OS X so I wanted it as a comment. If I can test I'll answer this later, but feel free to answer it yourself with xattr - your thanks is all the reward I need.